# Universal covering of $n$ punctured 2-sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Actually, I just want to understand first sentence of [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282846/universal-covering-of-a-2-sphere-without-n-points). It says that

> Let $X$ be the $\mathbb{CP}_{1}$ with $n$ points deleted. Let $n \geq 3$. If I understand correctly, the universal covering of $X$ is isomorphic to the upper half plane as a complex analytic space.

And the answer is related to Fuchsian group, but I still do not find a introductory paper about that. Could you explain this statement, or just give some reference about why Fuchsian group is related to universal covering of $X$?

Comment: For starters, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you very much!

Comment: Uniformization theorem reduces the problem to proving that the universal cover of $X$ is not biholomorphic to ${\mathbb C}$. This follows, for instance, that the fundamental group of $X$ is free nonabelian since the group $Aff({\mathbb C})$ contains no discrete free nonabelian subgroups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to know the **Uniformization Theorem**:

**Theorem.** Every simply-connected Riemann surface $X$ is biholomorphic to a **model surface** which is either $S^2$ or ${\mathbb C}$ of the hyperbolic plane $H^2$ (the upper half-plane if you like).

Depending on which of the three models occur, one calls $X$ **spherical**, **euclidean** or **hyperbolic**. (Sadly, this terminology is inconsistent with the AG terminology, where "elliptic" means "euclidean" while "rational" means "spherical" and "general type" is "hyperbolic".) The same applies to (connected) surfaces $Y$ which are covered by $X$: Such a surface is biholomorphic to the quotient of a model surface by a discrete group $G$, of biholomorphic automorphisms, $G\cong \pi_1(Y)$, acting freely (without fixed points) on $X$.  Now, the question becomes which groups $G$ can act in such a way on the model surfaces. The group $Aut({\mathbb C})$ of conformal automorphisms of ${\mathbb C}$ consists of complex affine transformations
$$
z\mapsto az+b.
$$
(One usually proves this in an undergraduate CA class.) Since $G<Aut({\mathbb C})$ is supposed to act freely, it follows that $a=1$ for all elements of $G$. Thus, $G$ is free abelian of rank $\le 2$. This implies that all surfaces of euclidean type have abelian fundamental group. Since $\pi_1$ of $n$ times punctured sphere is free of rank $n-1$, if $n\ge 3$ then this group is nonabelian, hence, the surface cannot have parabolic type. It obviously cannot have elliptic type. Thus, we conclude that such a surface is the quotient of the hyperbolic plane by a group of automorphisms (hyperbolic isometric) acting properly discontinuously and freely. The same argument shows that every connected RS of euclidean type is either $T^2$ (aka an "ellipic curve"), or is conformal to ${\mathbb C}^\times$ or to ${\mathbb C}$.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for such a detailed explanation :) I will definitely study uniformization theorem well to understand your writing precisely.